# SQL Table Columns in Sharepoint Exernal Data Types

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

I have a database in another server. I use sharepoint designer and BCS to create an external content type. All the columns are available in this external type. But the problem is that when I create an external list and the operations like read, two of my columns are not available at all in this list. These fields are Int64. Is there any convention that is required for accessing these fields in sharepoint?